# Kotlin Library directory location

Tags: java, kotlin

I have downloaded the Apache common library.  Where should I put it in my directory structure?

Not at all sure where it should go and also how to link to it in Gradle.  ( would be nice to be able to link to it with the dependencies popup, but you have to hard type it in )

Comment: You shouldn't be downloading libraries yourself - Gradle will manage dependencies for you. The libraries you need can be put in your build.gradle. Did you check the docs, e.g. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, Gradle is made for downloading the libraries for you. Just declare the library coordinates in your `build.gradle(.kts)`, for example:

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
}
```

As a side note, in Kotlin you shouldn't need any Apache Commons library, most of these utilities are already in the Kotlin stdlib